# Yii login error when trying to do authentication against a user db table

Tags: php, authentication, yii

I am pretty new in Yii, and I am following the famous blog tutorial. However, I'm having a problem with user authentication. User authentication is performed in a class implementing the [IUserIdentity] interface:

```
class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity
{
private $_id;

/**
 * Authenticates a user.
 * @return boolean whether authentication succeeds.
 */
public function authenticate()
{
    $user=User::model()->find('LOWER(username)=?',array(strtolower($this->username)));


    if($user===null)
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
    else if(!$user->validatePassword($this->password))
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
    else
    {
        $this->_id=$user->id;
        $this->username=$user->username;
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
    }
    return $this->errorCode==self::ERROR_NONE;
}

/**
 * @return integer the ID of the user record
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->_id;
}
}
```

Instead of storing the plain password in the database, I store the hash result of the password and a randomly generated salt key. When validating the user-entered password, I compare the hash results, instead.

```
class User extends CActiveRecord
{  ...
   public function validatePassword($password)
    {
     return $this->hashPassword($password,$this->salt)===$this->password; }
   public function hashPassword($password,$salt)
   {
     return md5($salt.$password); }
}
```

And this is the standard Yii Login:

```
/**
 * Logs in the user using the given username and password in the model.
 * @return boolean whether login is successful
 */
public function login()
{
    if($this->_identity===null)
    {
        $this->_identity=new UserIdentity($this->username,$this->password);
        $this->_identity->authenticate();
    }
    if($this->_identity->errorCode===UserIdentity::ERROR_NONE)
    {
        $duration=$this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0; // 30 days
        Yii::app()->user->login($this->_identity,$duration);
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

The problem is that, when I try to login with demo/demo, I get

> *Incorrect username or password*

I checked the database and username and password are correctly saved in the table. 
Sorry if my question is very stupid. Any help will be appretiated.

Thanks,
Mahsa

Comment: Looks fine so far. Check what is the `UserIdentity::errorCode`. Are you using the same salt when you create new user and when you check authentication?

Comment: Can you explain more about how I can check to see if it uses the same salt?

Comment: what is saved in your database as password? md5($salt . $password) ? Where is you salt? Hard coded in the model, or saved in the database?

Comment: Yes, the password is saved in the database using md5($salt . $password), and the salt is also saved in the database.

Comment: @MahsaTeimourikia, please show your save function, when you store your hashed password

Comment: Well as I am following the tutorial, there is no save function! This is all I got. I guess the demo/demo username is saved in the database by default... If I'm wrong give me more instructions to find it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard practice is to

```
<?php
function createHash( $password ) {
    $salt = getRandomBytes(8);
    $hash = $salt . hash($salt . $password);
    return $hash; // $hash is what you would store in, for example, your database
}

function checkHash( $password, $hash ) {
    $salt = substr($hash, 0, 8);
    $ok = ($salt . hash($salt . $password) == $hash);
    return $ok;
}
```

It looks like you do not prepend the `$salt` value to your hash-result.

**Note:**
The use of md5 (and sha1) is considered insecure nowadays. Take a look at [BCrypt Hash (CRYPT_BLOWFISH) for crypt](http://php.net/crypt).

```
<?php
// Same as above, but will use BCrypt hash (if PHP >= 5.3)
function createHash( $password ) {
    $salt = '$2a$08$'.getRandomBytes(22);
    $hash = crypt($password, $salt);
    return $hash; // $hash is what you would store in, for example, your database
}

function checkHash( $password, $hash ) {
    $ok = (crypt($password, $hash) == $hash);
    return $ok;
}
```